# Google Cloud Compute Engine switched external IP address

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a server running on Google Cloud Compute Engine, and I've stopped the server for doing restart to all services running on.

I had this external IP address: "104.198.212.61", but now for some reason the external IP address changed to: "35.184.34.236".

The issue is that I have directed a domain and an SSL certificate to that specific IP address, so is there any way to restore the previous IP address?

It is quite critical to change the address back because all of what I've developed is running upon those addresses and to change the domain and the SSL certificate to that address is quite problematic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can recover the old IP address. Every virtual machine gets by default an [ephemeral external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress). At this moment, probably there is another virtual machine in Google Cloud that has that particular address you want.

You can [reserve](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#reserve_new_static) a static address before creating a new VM or you can [promote](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#promote_ephemeral_ip) an ephemeral address to a reserved one in case you already have a VM.